# Do I have to do ghusl if I only notice the stains but don't recall ejaculating?

Tags: ghusl

I noticed in my underwear that there was a stain from a white liquid that came out, but I didn't notice it at the time so will I have to to ghusl for this? The stain also didn’t have a smell to it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely and do not watch these types of videos because it is forbidden Allah ordered us to lower our gazes and you should stop this act and repent to Allah and see his forgiveness.